# How to fix rectangle height in Reportviewer Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, rdlc, reportviewer

I am working with Visual Studio 2010 ReportViewer WinForms.
I have been unable to figure out how to fix the rectangle height in a report.  I've tried using a table within the rectangle, also a table in a sub report that is placed in the rectangle of the main report with no success.

Basically, I am setting up an invoice-type report that must keep its' form and should not be allowed to grow so that elements are pushed onto a second page.

Answer (score 0):

Both rectangle and tables will always grow vertically based on the content. There is no way to really stop this.

There are a couple of properties that might be able to help you get the correct page breaking in place:

- `KeepTogether` indicates whether to keep all sections of the data region together on pane page.
  When set on *true* and the region is to large to fit the page, this will add a page-break before the start of the region to try and fit as much as possible on a single page.
  So if you wish for the region to start at the initial location but break afterwards, make sure this is to *false*.
- `PageBreak` has the parameter `BreakLocation` which can be used to determine a fixed place to add a page-break. You can set it on *Start*, *End*, *StartAndEnd* or *Between*.
  You could split your report in fixed pages and use these to add standard page-breaks in the desired (fixed) locations.

These properties alone might not be enough to get your desired result. Especially when working with tables it is hard to add a page-break after a fixed amount of rows.
It is hard to give you a detailed description of a possible approach with the amount of information you gave me, but here is some general advice.

You should split your data in the correct intervals before sending the datasource to the reporter. You can for example use grouping to place them in the correct intervals and add page-breaks based on the grouping.
Another solution is to add them in separate containers, this will require you to have enough spare data regions at your disposal. If there are too many you can always hide the empty ones based on an expression set for the `Hidden` property.

It won't be easy to set this up correctly so that it can dynamically grow. It takes a lot of puzzling from your end but pretty much any layout should be possible to achieve.
I wish I could give you a more specific solution to your problem and am willing to help you further if you give me an example to work with. But ultimately this is something you should be able to achieve on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Between the above and making use of the page footer, I should be able to create what I need.